この前一度 meaning and breakdown explanation
What is the meaning of "この前一度", is it the same as "この間" ?
For example :

この前一度、携帯をなくしちゃったんです。


この前一度 means "once previously".
So, in your example sentence, this would be

Once previously, I lost my phone.

この前 essentially means "before now" in this context.
一度 means "once"
この間 would mean more like "recently" or "around this time".
